# Positioning figure and table in figure

Tags: matplotlib, figure

I'm trying to put both a plot and a table in a figure, but I want some whitespace to separate the two. How do I position the table/plot at arbitrary positions? What I have now is the table of values showing up IMMEDIATELY under the x-axis (so that it's actually colliding into my axis labels...)

I don't know matplotlib at all...The documentation is not written very well either...

Comment: use subplot?  play with hspace?  please post what you're currently doing.  debugging invisible code is hard.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835650/while-creating-table-underneath-axis-on-a-plot-is-there-a-way-to-create-some-whi ?

Answer (score 3):

To position something in a figure you have to use the function set_position([left, bottom, width, height]). Example:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.axes().set_position([0.15, 0.20, 0.80, 0.70])
```