# while creating table underneath axis on a plot, is there a way to create some whitespace between the axis and the table using matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create table inside a plot right underneath the axis of the plot using matplotlib

I am using the plt.table function to do this

However, when i create the table, it's created right on top of the axis, hence overlaps with the axislabels

Is there a way to create the white space in between

the code looks something like this

```
    for key, value in arrayToPlot.iteritems():
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
        if value["HorErr"]:
            cdf = []
            #calculate percentile stats for the value["HorErr"]
            cdfArrayPointer[key]["HorErr"]["percentileStats"]=libMath.percentileForListofPercentiles( value["HorErr"], PERCENTILE, validPointsOnly = True )
            # now calculate the cdf values
            cdfArrayPointer[key]["HorErr"]["cdf"] = libMath.cdf( value["HorErr"], 2, 400, validPointsOnly = True)
            for k, v in cdfArrayPointer[key]["HorErr"]["cdf"].iteritems():
                cdf.append( v )                
            #plot the cdf value
            ax1.plot(cdf, 'o-', label = ('HorErr for ' + str( key) ), color = getColour(key), markersize=3)
            plt.title("CDF Plot of 2D-Horizontal Error", size = 8)
            plt.ylabel('Percentile %', size = 7)
            plt.xlabel('Horizontal Error [m]', size = 6)
            plt.axis([0, 150, 0, 110])
            leg = plt.legend(loc = 4)
            setLegendSize( leg, 7)
            # creating the table to be drawn on the axis
            tableTexts["rows"].append(key)
            tableTexts["rowColour"].append(getColour(key))
            if (len(tableTexts["col"]) == 0):
                tableTexts["col"] = tuple(cdfArrayPointer[key]["HorErr"]["percentileStats"].keys())

            tableTexts["values"].append(cdfArrayPointer[key]["HorErr"]["percentileStats"].values())


    the_table = plt.table(cellText=tableTexts["values"], rowLabels= tableTexts["rows"], rowColours= tableTexts["rowColour"] ,colLabels= tableTexts["col"], loc="bottom")
```

Answer (score 1):

What about breaking your figure up using `subplot`?
You could have the axis in one subplot, and the table in another. (See example near bottom of page [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/pyplot_tutorial.html))

I can illustrate further if you can't follow.

Comment: instead of adding another subplot for the figure as i already had
 different subplots, i just changed the location of the table and         played around with the cell width. ex.

        plt.table(cellText=tableTexts["values"], rowLabels= tableTexts["rows"], rowColours= tableTexts["rowColour"] ,colLabels= tableTexts["col"], colWidths = [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2], loc="center right")